# Bad Request. Could not decode Response: Parse Server

Tags: php, parse-platform, parse-server

I am getting a `Bad Request. Could not decode response: (4) Syntax error` when I am trying to query from parse server. I do not get this error when trying locally. My php version is 7.1 locally and on my production server. I believe it has to do with my data. For example this object `Curl - 45° Prone Inc. - DB - Sup. Grip` works but this one `Curl - 30° - Inc. - DB - Zottman` will cause the error. These values will be entered by users so I will need some way of either catching and changing them or fixing the issue of querying them. I do not have any issues querying other classes that do not contain special characters.

Comment: I'm getting this with the php SDK and Laravel, but only on my production server. My database already has emojis in some string fields, and the iOS and Android SDKs handle them fine. My local server (php 7.1.30) is also fine, but I get this error pulling some documents using the php SDK on the production server (php 7.1.33). Can the minor update make that much difference?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I just used `htmlentities` to convert the special characters to accepted ones before saving to the database. Hope this helps someone else.